# Best practice to handle non initialised properties in class based components

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I want to handle my undefined property in my class based vue component. I want to hide my div, when the property is undefined with v-if. Currently vue is giving me the error that the property is referenced during render and it is undefined.

I initialize this property as soon as I've selected an item in my component and as long as nothing is selected I want it undefined to know that nothing is selected.

```
interface MyCustomObject{
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
...
...
...
<template>
  <div v-if="form">
    ...
  </div>
</template>

@Component({})
export default class MyCustomComponent extends Vue {
  form: MyCustomObject|undefined;
}
```

Initializing my object with some placeholder data is a terrible solution in my opinion.
I found a workaround, which is not better at all, with changing all fields in my interface to optional, so that I can initialize my object as an empty object. This would lead me to check all properties of the object for undefined in my code.

```
interface MyCustomObject{
    id?: number;
    name?: string;
}
...
...
...
form: MyCustomObject|undefined = {};
```

**I know this can be handled in other ways not using class based components or using javascript, but this is not what I'm looking for.**

Comment: Null those instead of undefined as those have an intention and are defined but "empty"

Comment: @Estradiaz This is so easy.... Thank you :D